# Bash on windows can't find class even after setting classpath

Tags: java, bash

I need to include .jar file when running the java class. When I use cmd on my windows, I can successfully run using the following command

```
java -cp .;MyLib.jar; MyClass
```

However when I tried to use bash on the same PC, I got error - can't find or load main class. I searched online and some say I needed to use `./*` instead of just `.` for the current directory. So far I tried these commands:

```
java -cp .:MyLib.jar: MyClass
java -cp ./*:MyLib.jar: MyClass
java -cp ".:MyLib.jar:" MyClass
java -cp "./*:MyLib.jar:" MyClass
```

only getting "ClassNotFoundException" every time.I know the class exists because if I switch to cmd when it runs fine. I was also able to run the class on bash shell on a mac using the following command

```
java -cp .:MyLib.jar: MyClass
```

Then I built a simple class and ran in bash without classpath

```
java MyTest
```

So using `-classpath` caused the issue. How do I include the current directory in bash? Why did it work on bash on a mac? Is it because I was running bash on windows? I am so puzzled by this problem.

And if it helps, I can compile in bash just not able to run the class. `javac -cp MyLib.jar MyClass.java` compiled the file in bash. I am working under the same directory where `MyClass.class` is.

Edit: the solution is `java -cp ".;MyLib.jar;" MyClass`. I thought I posted here for anyone who ran into the same issue as I did. Please see comments for explanation. Thank you torek!

Comment: Java paths are not related to Git at all. There may be some exportable environment variable you can set *in* bash (or any other shell), but that's a Java thing. It's not clear to me what you mean by "git cmd": did you mean CMD.EXE? That's not part of Git either. I do have one suspicion here: perhaps your Java demands semicolons, not colons; you'd need to quote these to keep bash from eating them for its own purposes, while CMD.EXE doesn't use semicolons so there's no need to quote them in CMD.EXE.

Comment: In other words, consider using `java -cp ".;mylib.jar;"` here, just as you did in CMD.EXE but with double quotes to protect the semicolons from bash.

Comment: Thank you two!! Yes semicolons worked!! I got both bash and cmd when installing git so I thought I'd test bash. sorry for calling it "git bash". bash is a Unix shell but apparently on windows it needs semicolons instead of colons?? I guess because it is running on windows?

Comment: You have a few things mixed together here: (1) bash is a shell, yes; it was originally written for Unix/Linux. Some people wanted to run it on Windows. They made (multiple) Windows ports of bash. (2) Git was originally written for Linux. It assumed you had a shell (sh, bash, any of various ones that are all sufficiently similar.) (3) People wanted Git on Windows. (4) People took one of the bash-for-Windows ports and included it in a Git distribution: hence "git-bash". It's not part of Git, it's just one of the Windows ports, included in Windows Git distributions.

Comment: Meanwhile, quite separately: Sun Microsystems created Java (on SunOS, a Unix variant). Unix people like colons in paths. Their marketers wanted Java everywhere, though, so they made ports to Windows. Windows people like semicolons where Unix people like colons. So, the Java-for-Windows people use semicolons (only! no colons, based on what you've observed) while the Java-for-Unix people use colons (perhaps only, perhaps semicolons too). This leads to Java tutorials showing colons (which is what I used to see in the past).

Comment: Meanwhile, bash is still what it is: a shell that uses semicolons to let you put multiple commands on one line, e.g., `for i in a b c; do echo $i; chmod +x $i; done` is valid bash syntax, running a loop (`for...`) and doing two commands inside the loop. Java still needs semicolons though. Running `java -cp .;mylib.jar` would, to bash, mean *run `java -cp .` then run `mylib.jar`*. Bash allows *escaping* its special characters, though, using backslash, single quotes, and double quotes - each one does something slightly different.

Comment: So, if you're in bash and need to pass a semicolon on to a command, you must quote it: `java -cp .\;mylib.jar\;` for instance, or `java -cp '.;mylib.jar;'`. That protects the semicolon from bash itself, passing it on to `java`. This is all necessary because bash itself is a full-blown programming language, with variables, loops, and so on.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! I did try semicolons without double quote and it didn’t work. Now I see why. It ran as multiple commands! torek Thank you again!!!